# Junit5 test configuration for Jersey test and SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, junit5

### Context

I want to test some Jersey resources in my application. I use JUnit5 and SpringBoot.
All my Jersey resources tests extends a JerseyConfiguration class which has a SpringBoot configuration to create/mock all application services used in the tests.
But so far, I cannot get rid of the following error :

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'appProperties';
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'getAppProperties': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'hasAccess'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
> value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value
> [${has.access}]

### Problem

**It seems that the AppProperties class is not loaded properly because it does not find the properties in application.properties file. However, all properties are set in this file under src/main/test/resources**

I tried different things without success such as
`@TestPropertySource(properties = {"has.access=true"})`
and
`@SpringBootTest(classes = {SpringTestConfig.class}, properties = "has.access=true")`
Also tried to mock the AppProperties like that in SpringTestConfig

```
@Bean
public AppProperties getAppProperties () {
    AppProperties props = new AppProperties ();
    props.setHasAccess(true);
    return props;
}
```

Here are some of the files of my test configuration
*MyTest.java*

```
public class MyTest extends JerseyConfiguration {
// some  @Autowired services
}
```

*JerseyConfiguration.java*

```
public abstract class JerseyConfiguration extends FastJerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final ResourceConfig config) {
        config.register(AuthenticationExceptionMapperProvider.class);
        config.register(AccessDeniedExceptionMapperProvider.class);
        config.register(JacksonObjectMapperProvider.class);
        config.packages("resources.package");
        config.property(
            "contextConfig",
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringTestConfig.class)
        );
    }
```

*SpringTestConfig.java*

```
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"some.beans.packages"})
    @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
    @Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
    public class SpringTestConfig {
        @Bean
        public AppProperties getAppProperties () {
           AppProperties props = new AppProperties();
           props.setHasAccess(true);
           return props;
        }
    ... some mocks
```

*AppProperties.java*

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppProperties {

    @Value("${has.access}")
    private boolean hasAccess;
```

And there is the `application.properties` file for tests under *src/main/test/resources* containing all the properties of AppProperties

### Partial solution

if I add `@PropertySource("/application.properties")` to `SpringTestConfig`  instead of `@TestPropertySource`, then it works but it does not seem an ideal solution to me